# scrapy Itemloader: how to load with Item()/dict

Tags: python, scrapy

If I have an Item() which is already populated, how would I load an itemloader with it?

For example

```
from scrapy import Item, ItemLoader, Field

class MyLoader(ItemLoader):
    desc_out = MapCompose(unicode.strip)

class MyItem(Item):
    desc = Field()


item = MyItem()
item['desc'] = "\r\t\n        some text            \t\n"
loader = MyLoader(item)
loader.load_item()
#output: {'desc': "\r\t\n        some text            \t\n"}


newloader = MyLoader(item = MyItem(**{'desc':'\n\ta\n'}))
loader.load_item()
#output still: {'desc': "\r\t\n        some text            \t\n"}
```

I want to use the loader to do some output processing, but in this example the whitespace is not getting stripped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loader doesn't process values you don't add via an `add_` method. You could subclass `ItemLoader`:

```
class ReloadableItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReloadableItemLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for key, value in self.item.iteritems():
            self._add_value(key, value)
```

Comment: Ok, this is an old post, but I had similar questions about ItemLoader and this has been helpful. But why not tell the OP to just redo his code and put add value in there?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the fields and add them to the loader using [`add_value()`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.ItemLoader.add_value):

```
item = MyItem()
item['desc'] = "\r\t\n        some text            \t\n"

loader = MyLoader()

for k, v in item.items():
    loader.add_value(k, v)

loader.load_item()  # {'desc': u'some text'}
```